# Opening file from server with ColdFustion

Tags: file, coldfusion, server

I have a piece of code that runs though a loop and gets all the file names that have been uploaded to an application.

```
<CFOUTPUT QUERY="findfiles">
   <A HREF="#file_destination##filename#">#title#</A>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

Not sure what the real problem is but when the user clicks on the link a error pops up that reads "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (d) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context." An example of the url is:
file:///d:/DOCS/UPLOADS/apps/1234_afxg2013%20Application%20rev1.doc

I am trying to grab files from the server. Some of these file names also contain spaces which might be causing the problem?? These files are stored on another server so I cant do a .../files anymore.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a URL using "file:///", it is looking at the clients machine if the browser even allows it.

You don't have enough information in your post to dissect it entirely. But in the end you need to have a URL that looks more like this: "http://www.bringqbasicback.com/aps/1234.doc".

I also suggest you do some research on keeping your web server secure. User uploaded files should not be stored in the web root and should be using a handler to retrieve them. But this is a whole 'nother topic and is not required.